# C# and WPF List Views And Sorting

Tags: c#, wpf

When you sort a List View why cant you sort it again there after?

The listbox holds Check boxes which are dynamically added.

```
(XAML)
<ListView Name="Main_List_View" />

(C#)
//The Dictionary list is being populated before this loop is run
Dictionary<string,string> list = new Dictionary<string,string>();

foreach(var item in list)
{
    CheckBox box = new CheckBox();
    box.Name = item.Key;
    box.Content = item.Value;
    Main_List_View.Items.Add(box);
}
```

Cool I loaded the list view with items now I sort them.

```
(C#)
Main_List_View.Items.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Content", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
```

The list is now sorted in Ascending successfully in Runtime.
But As soon as I Sort the same listview to Descending with a button Nothing Happens what could it be the reason?

```
(C#)
//Button event here
Main_List_View.Items.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Content", ListSortDirection.Descending));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you add Descending SortDescription, clear the available SortDescriptions.

```
 Main_List_View.Items.SortDescriptions.Clear();
            Main_List_View.Items.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Content", ListSortDirection.Descending));
```